# React-navigation stack horizontal screen gesture for Android. (react-navigation/stack)

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

On Android, I am aware that the stack screen animation can be controlled to be horizontal when using the `react-navigation-stack` library with the `transitionConfig` prop. However, it doesn't seem to work for the `react-navigation/stack` library, or rather it doesn't have any support for it. Have anyone managed to make it work with `react-navigation/stack`? Or are there any way to combine both libraries, as i would find it a waste to rewrite my codes in another library just for this small issue. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There is ```gestureDirection``` option for Stack Navigator. Have you tried [it](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#animation-related-options)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this -

[Working Example](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/gesture-example-stacknavigator)

[Youtube Tutorial for Navigation Gestures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PvjV96CNPqM)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Easing } from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  CardStyleInterpolators,
} from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Notifications"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const timingConfig = {
  animation: 'timing',
  config: {
    duration: 200,
    easing: Easing.linear,
  },
};

const options = {
  gestureEnabled: true,
  cardStyleInterpolator: CardStyleInterpolators.forHorizontalIOS,
  transitionSpec: {
    open: timingConfig,
    close: timingConfig,
  },
};

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={options} />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Notifications"
        component={NotificationsScreen}
        options={options}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Profile"
        component={ProfileScreen}
        options={options}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Settings"
        component={SettingsScreen}
        options={options}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: After experimenting around with it a bit, I realized that the horizontal gesture effect on Android works without the `transitionSpec` option, and `cardStyleInterpolator` was sufficient.